# Reversed order of bars in grouped barplot with coord_flip

Tags: r, ggplot2

Using the code from [here](https://github.com/edamame-course/datacarpentry/blob/master/lessons/tidy-data/01-intro.md), I have realized something I do not understand:

```
library(ggplot2)

LoTRdata <- structure(list(Film = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("The Fellowship Of The Ring", 
"The Return Of The King", "The Two Towers"), class = "factor"), 
    Race = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("Elf", "Hobbit", 
    "Man"), class = "factor"), Gender = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L
    ), .Label = c("Female", "Male"), class = "factor"), Words = c(1229L, 
    971L, 14L, 3644L, 0L, 1995L, 331L, 513L, 0L, 2463L, 401L, 
    3589L, 183L, 510L, 2L, 2673L, 268L, 2459L)), .Names = c("Film", 
"Race", "Gender", "Words"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-18L))

p <- ggplot(LoTRdata, aes(x = Race, y = Words, fill = Film))
p + geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
  coord_flip() + guides(fill = guide_legend())
```

[image]

Why is the order of the bars reversed? And how can I change the order of the bars

I am aware that I could use `guides(fill = guide_legend(reverse = TRUE))` but then the order of the bars and the legend are both reversed (the legend is not alphabetically ordered anymore).

In contrast to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33966908/reorder-dodge-bar-plots-ggplot2), where the order of each grouped bars is depending on the highest occurence, I just want to know how to reverse the order of each group (the same order it would be as if I wouldn't use `coord_flip`).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [reorder dodge bar plots (ggplot2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33966908/reorder-dodge-bar-plots-ggplot2)

Comment: Have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33966908/reorder-dodge-bar-plots-ggplot2); the issue seems to be the identical, even with the same data.

Comment: I found this post before, that is actually where my question came from. Because in the last answer, the order is dependent on the highest occurence for each group of bars. However, I am trying to find out how to flip the order of the bars after using `coord_flip`.

Comment: `aes(x = Race, y = Words, fill = forcats::fct_rev(Film))`?

Comment: The reason this happens, by the way, is that the groups are dodge increasing by x (now y), and (0, 0) is in the lower left hand corner. So the first group (red) is put closest to 0, which is lowest.

Comment: `scale_x_discrete(limits=rev)`

Answer (score 3):

```
p <- ggplot(LoTRdata, aes(x = Race, y = Words, fill = Film))
p + geom_bar(stat = "identity", position =  position_dodge2(reverse=TRUE)) +
coord_flip()
```

Maybe you could start play with position_dodge2 function

Comment: This worked for me after trying LOADS of workarounds.